# Woocommerce show notes to customer on account dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Have this code in: woocommerce/templates/myaccount/view-order.php

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
$notes = $order->get_customer_order_notes();
?>
<p>
<?php if ( $notes ) : ?>
    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Order updates', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
    <ol class="woocommerce-OrderUpdates commentlist notes">
        <?php foreach ( $notes as $note ) : ?>
        <li class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate comment note">
            <div class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-inner comment_container">
                <div class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-text comment-text">
                    <p class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-meta meta"><?php echo date_i18n( esc_html__( 'l jS \o\f F Y, h:ia', 'woocommerce' ), strtotime( $note->comment_date ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>
                    <div class="woocommerce-OrderUpdate-description description">
                        <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( $note->comment_content ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It shows the notes I can send to customer in WC orders. That info is under My account -> orders -> view order for the customer but I'd like to display that note in customer dashboard instead of view order.
I tried copying it to the dashboard.php but it just threw an error and said that get_customer_order_notes() is null.

I'm a beginner in php and it's my first WC site so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What code exactly did you copy over,The above? You'll need to call the WC_Order class with the correct order ID, ref: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_customer_note

Comment: The above yes. I'm not 100% sure how to call the order notes via wc_order